# How to search for hidden files and folders in dolphin?

Tags: kde, dolphin, file-search

I'd like to be able to search for hidden files and folders in dolphin.

Currently I was trying to search for backups of the .bash_history file but no results showed up despite hidden files being set to visible in dolphin.

Is there a way to make dolphin show hidden files and folders in the search results if hidden files are visible in the folder? If it's not possible with dolphin as is maybe there's an extension for it?

[This forum post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=132673) and the bug report linked therein are relevant.

An improvised solution is to search for files with `find . -name .bash_history`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible with the current version in Debian 10.

Instead one could use KFind for this.

There is an issue about this [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416087).